# Gazebo 1.8.1 turns into black

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to launch my own world of a circuit but it is not possible, Gazebo turns into black and I cannot see my world with my robot. I can connect to the robot cameras but I don't see anything. The model of the circuit is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="heightmap">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link2">
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <heightmap>     
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/terrain_detail.jpg</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/terrain_detail.jpg</normal>
              <size>50</size>
            </texture>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>50</size>
            </texture>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/beigeWall.jpg</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>20</size>
            </texture>  
            <blend>
              <min_height>0</min_height>
              <fade_dist>0</fade_dist>
            </blend>
            <blend>
              <min_height>0.01</min_height>
              <fade_dist>0</fade_dist>
            </blend>     
            <uri>model://jarama/images/jaramaCircuitoRetocado.png</uri>
            <size>50 50 1</size>
            <pos>0 0 0</pos>
          </heightmap>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Basically it loads a black&white image with the circuit and constructs it with walls and a blue line. It is to do a follow-line behaviour based on the Pioneer 2DX.

I'm running Gazebo on Ubuntu 13.04 64bits. In Ubuntu 12.04 64bits I can load this world but it works so slowly because of not having drivers of my integrated graphic card (Intel HD4000), now developed for Ubuntu 13.04.

Do you know if I'm missing something or if I can fix that?

Thank you,

Borja.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3094/gazebo-1.8.1-turns-into-black/) by [bmenendez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/372/bmenendez/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try loading another world or any models from the database (insert model) and see if you can see anything there.
If a basic world or models from the model database work, you can try to load a height-map such as the one [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/949f1b635de1b2841619ea4407a8bbea580c34fd/gazebo_models/environments/vrc_heightmap_1/model.sdf?at=default).

Let me know if that worked

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) with karma: 349 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bmenendez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/372/bmenendez/) on 2013-06-05**:
Hi ffurrer. First of all, thank you for your answer :) I tried before to load another world and that's ok, it loads the world properly (for example, I tried to load a world just with the Pioneer 2DX and some walls and it worked). I can also load the model you showed me, so I don't really know where it is failing. The image (jaramaCircuitoRetocado.png) is just a black&white image and it works in Ubuntu 12.04 without graphic drivers but not in Ubuntu 13.04 with graphic drivers :-/